# Intermittent 'Dead Click' Issue with 'FREE DOWNLOAD' Button on WordPress Website

Tags: wordpress, web, download

Website: `www.veeforu.com`

I run an image downloading website where I use this PHP script:

```php
<?php
echo "<h6>Free Download this image , veeforu </h6>";

$folder_path = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();

echo '<a class="download_image" href="' . $folder_path . '" download>FREE DOWNLOAD</a>';
```

This triggers an automatic image download for the user on click.

Problem Description:

I am the owner of a WordPress website, and we have been experiencing an intermittent issue with our "FREE DOWNLOAD" button.

Users have reported instances where clicking on the button does not trigger any action or response, resulting in a 'dead click.' This issue occurs sporadically, making it challenging to identify the root cause and find a suitable solution.

Here are some key points about the problem:

1. Intermittent Occurrence: The 'dead click' problem with the "FREE DOWNLOAD" button happens only occasionally, and it's not consistently reproducible.
2. No Specific Pattern: Users have encountered this issue on various devices, browsers, and operating systems. There seems to be no specific pattern regarding when or where the problem occurs.
3. No JavaScript Errors: We have checked the browser's developer console when the issue happens, but there are no visible JavaScript errors or warnings related to the button's functionality.
4. WordPress Environment: Our website is built on WordPress, and the "FREE DOWNLOAD" button functionality is implemented using JavaScript and CSS.

I don't know what to do.